# How do I use tlmgr to install make4ht?

Tags: tlmgr, texlive-2020

I am trying to use make4ht to convert a .tex file into an xml file. Since apparently my Texlive was outdated, I went through the process of installing the 2020 version manually ("vanilla" using [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)). Now, I am trying to use tlmgr to install make4ht

```
 tlmgr install make4ht
```

but it says '/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5'. I am not sure if I am using the wrong package name: CTAN says its included in TexLive, ubuntu suggests to do

```
 sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

but after getting through all the trouble reinstalling TexLive I thought I should give tlmgr a shot. I just cant figure out how to use it properly... Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you installed the debian/ubuntu texlive via apt you should update the same way not via tlmgr (usually)

Comment: no I did not install it via apt, I did it manually.

Comment: Oh you mean you installed the vanilla texlive from tug, in that case yes always use tlmgr and never apt to update it. In that case you would have it by default but if you chose a minimal scheme originally `sudo tlmgr info make4ht` will tell you if it is installed or not and `sudo tlmgr install make4ht`  will install it if it is not installed

Comment: if you still get a verify checksum error that means (most likely) there is an issue at the ctan mirror you are using, try again a bit later or if it keeps happening try a different mirror.

Comment: thank you very much! yes I meant I installed it vanilla ;) your instructions work except that I need to do it without sudo. And somehow I need to add the texlive 2020 path manually every time, otherwise it takes 2019 (that i was sure i deleted thoroughly). But at least its a different problem now ;)

Comment: you need or not need sudo depending on whether you installed it originally in your own account or via sudo. You need to put the 2020 bin directory at the front of the PATH in your .profile or .bash_profile or whatever startup script yo use